# minikube start error to pull new external images, you may need to configure a proxy

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to start minikube but it gives me this error

```
this vM is having trouble accessing https://k8s.gcr.io
To pull new external images, you may need to configure a proxy:
https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/networking/proxy/
```

I tried docker and HyperV and VirtualBox same error kubectl is working fine but whenever I tried to pull a namespace like Kubernetes-dashboard I get errimagepull

Comment: Please do not post images of text. Instead paste text directly. Your VM where you run minikube has no access to the Internet.

Comment: Done I changed the text. How ?? I'm new to this virtualisation world

Comment: I'm getting the same issue, and what's strange is, if I use minikube ssh to connect to the VM (in VirtualBox), and use curl https://k8s.gcr.io it connects - though I would note it delivers a "redirect" page.

So then I tried (using -L to follow redirect) curl -L https://k8s.gcr.io

And got back a page with a lot of html.

So, the VM doesn't seem to have any connectivity issue, and yet I get that error. Could it be that k8s is trying to connect too early in the boot process?

Answer (score 5):

#### Option 1:

- Try to set up a proxy
- https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/vpn_and_proxy/

```bash
### Linux 
# Set your proxy
export HTTP_PROXY=http://<proxy hostname:port>
export HTTPS_PROXY=https://<proxy hostname:port>

### Windows
set HTTP_PROXY=http://<proxy hostname:port>
set HTTPS_PROXY=https://<proxy hostname:port>

# Start minikube  
minikube start
```

---

#### Option 2:

```bash
minikube start --image-repository=auto
```

---

#### Option 3:

```bash
# Remove old content (minikube context)
minikube delete

# Start minikube with docker driver in case you have been using something else
minikube start --driver=docker
```

---

#### Option 4. (If you are in china)

```bash
$ minikube start            \
  --driver=docker           \
  ##
  ## Try with or without this flag if it's not working for you
  ## [optional] --image-mirror-country
  --image-mirror-country=cn \ 
  --registry-mirror=https://registry.docker-cn.com \ 
  --image-repository=registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers
```

Comment: Option 2 , 3 Doasn't work Option 1 which value I have to give to HTTp_Proxy I'm using windows

Comment: Yeah let me just set up a proxy. What a great answer. Brilliant

Comment: In Option 1, What are the value? @CodeWizard

Answer (score 1):

tried all suggestions above. Simply, restarting docker solved.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
minikube start --docker-env HTTP_PROXY=https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/networking/proxy/
```